# Фильтр пользователей Telegram Bot (aiogram)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть бот, где реализовано, чтобы пользователю высылался документ при нажатии на инлайн кнопку

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InputFile


bot = Bot(token = 'token')
mybot = Dispatcher(bot)

@mybot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    station = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Файл', callback_data='Файл')
    markup.add(station)
    await message.reply('Выберите просмотр', reply_markup=markup)
    
@mybot.callback_query_handler(text='Файл')
async def menu_index(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer_document(document="document_ID")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  executor.start_polling(mybot)
```

Хочется реализовать ограничение/фильтр пользователей на допуск к файлам, то есть только определенному пользователю придет файл, а если он не входит в список разрешенных пользователей, то ему такое сообщение и придет. Однако, даже не знаю с какой стороны к этому вопросу подобраться.

Подскажите, может кто уже реализовывал?

Comment: Сделать список юзеров по айди, и потом просто делать проверку есть ли юзер в списке, не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена
Если кому интересно, то вот код:

```
    filters_btns = {
    'btn1' : [user_id123, user_id321]}

@mybot.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data in mapping_btns_path_filter)
async def menu_index(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.from_user.id not in mapping_btns_path_filter[call.data][2]:
        return
    path = path1 + mapping_btns_path_filter[call.data][0] + date
    file = InputFile(io.BytesIO(sftp.open(path, 'rb').read()), filename=mapping_btns_path_filter[call.data][1])
    await call.message.answer_document(document=file)
```

Конечно, тут еще отсылка файла и подключение к словарю путей файлов и все такое. Но кусок кода можно вырезать, если кому пригодится